# Can't get image to preview in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a social media app that allows you to post either text or image posts. I'm struggling to be able to show image as preview when posting.

It doesn't seem to be able to set the imageData, or does so async and idk how to await the result so it shows in my preview.

Heres the parent component:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { collection, addDoc, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useUserContext } from "../../../services/user-context";
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";
import TextPost from "./TextPost";
import ImagePost from "./ImagePost";

export const CreatePostModal = ({ open, setOpen }) => {
  const { user } = useUserContext();
  const db = getFirestore();
  const storage = getStorage();
  const [imageData, setImageData] = useState(null);

  const handleImageUpload = async (e) => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (img) => setImageData(img.target.result);
      reader.readAsDataURL(await e.target.files[0]);
      console.log(imageData);
    }
  };

  const pictureUploadRef = ref(storage, "posts/");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(e.target);
    console.log(formData);
    const title = formData.get("title");
    const content = formData.get("content");

    const postRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "posts"), {
      comments: [],
      content: content,
      likes: [],
      picture: imageData,
      technologies: [],
      timestamp: new Date(),
      title: title,
      userAvatar: "avatarUrl",
      userID: user.id,
    });
  };
  return imageData ? (
    <div>
      <ImagePost
        open={open}
        setOpen={setOpen}
        handleImageUpload={handleImageUpload}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
      />
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <TextPost
        open={open}
        setOpen={setOpen}
        handleImageUpload={handleImageUpload}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        imageData={imageData}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here is child:

```js
import React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Modal from "@mui/material/Modal";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import ImageIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Image";

const TitleInput = styled.textarea`
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-size: 25px;
  resize: none;
  &:focus-visible {
    outline: none;
  }
  &::placeholder {
    color: black;
  }
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0 15px;
  color: black;
`;

const ContentInput = styled.textarea`
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-size: 20px;
  resize: none;
  &:focus-visible {
    outline: none;
  }
  &::placeholder {
    color: black;
  }
`;

const ImageContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  //   background-color: red;
`;

const style = {
  position: "absolute",
  height: "50%",
  minWidth: "400px",
  minHeight: "550px",
  width: "40%",
  top: "50%",
  left: "50%",
  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  bgcolor: "#f0f2f5",
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4,
  borderRadius: "20px",
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "flex-start",
  alignItems: "center",
  flexDirection: "column",
  outline: "none",
  padding: "15px 25px 25px",
};

const ImagePost = ({
  open,
  setOpen,
  handleImageUpload,
  handleSubmit,
  imageData,
}) => {
  return (
    <Modal
      open={open}
      onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
    >
      <Box sx={style}>
        <Typography
          id="modal-modal-title"
          variant="h4"
          component="h2"
          sx={{ fontSize: "30px" }}
        >
          Create a post
        </Typography>
        <div
          style={{
            border: "0.5px solid #a6a6a6",
            width: "100%",
            margin: "15px 0 0",
          }}
        />
        <form style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
          <TitleInput placeholder="Post title" required name="title" />
          <ContentInput placeholder="Post content" required name="content" />
          <ImageContainer>
            {imageData ? <img src={imageData} alt="" /> : <p>failed</p>}
          </ImageContainer>
          <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <label htmlFor="upload-button">
              <input
                onChange={handleImageUpload}
                accept="image/*"
                id="upload-button"
                type="file"
                style={{ display: "none" }}
              />
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                size="large"
                sx={{ ml: "-70px" }}
                component="span"
              >
                <ImageIcon />
              </Button>
            </label>
            <label htmlFor="submit-button">
              <Button
                type="submit"
                id="submit-button"
                variant="contained"
                size="large"
                color="success"
                sx={{ ml: "10px", width: "150px" }}
                onClick={handleSubmit}
              >
                Submit
              </Button>
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </Box>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default ImagePost;
```

Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1 key thing that you are missing here is that react state updates are not instantaneous, they are scheduled. You make api call which is async and may complete after the page has already been rendered. you may wanna look into [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks, however the api call doesn't have anything to do with the problem I'm having. Since I'm setting the imageData as FileReader data which is done in the browser